# Is there a script to check existing printer name and rename it?

Tags: vbscript

As mentioned in title, I have to change the client side printer name and unified the name of them.

For example there are lots of workstation who has installed same printer with different named. So, is there any script that i can use to change the name by checking the existing name ?

`(e.g. : HP_printer_4300_ABC, HP_4300_ABC and 4300_printer_ABC to change to ABC )`

Comment: Since you do not have your own script for this then I believe you should ask the question on SuperUser.

Answer (score 0):

You can query and change your printers' names using WMI

Here's a simple  script that I just coded which should do what you want

```
strComputer = "." ' Local computer
strOldNameContains = "_ABC" ' The target printers to rename contains this string 
strNewName = "ABC" ' New name for the printer

Set objWMIService = GetObject("winmgmts:\\" & strComputer & "\root\cimv2")

Set colPrinters =  objWMIService.ExecQuery ("Select * From Win32_Printer ")

For Each objPrinter in colPrinters

    ' Uncomment this for debugging
    'msgbox objPrinter.Name 

    if instr(objPrinter.Name,strOldNameContains)>0 then
        msgbox "Changing printer name from '" & objPrinter.Name & "' to '" & strNewName & "'"
        objPrinter.RenamePrinter(strNewName)
    end if

Next
```

Adapt the strings on top if needed, and remove the `msgbox` when you are ready

Comment: Thanks for help ! I will try and test it.